# Value of React input field persists when clicking

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, default-value

I'm trying to use a fetched value from DB as an initial value (shown until the component is clicked) of an input field.

However, when clicking on or typing in the input field, `value` of the input field persists meaning that a new value cannot be entered.

Component's file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import InputItem from './InputItem';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Props {
    income: string;
    setIncome: (value: string) => void; 
    totalExpenses: number;
    currencySymbol: string;
}

const IncomeExpensesContainer: React.FC<Props> = ({
        income,
        setIncome, 
        totalExpenses, 
        currencySymbol,
    }: Props) => {

    // Initializing didMount as false
    const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);

    // Setting didMount to true upon mounting
    useEffect(() => { setDidMount(true) }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
        if (didMount) {
            axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/income')
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/income', 
            {
                income: income
            });
        }
    }, [didMount,income]);
 
    return (
        <Grid container spacing={1} className="income-expenses-container">
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <InputItem 
                    onBlur={setIncome}
                    title="Income" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Your income" 
                    value={income}
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} className="centered">
                <h3>Total Expenses</h3>
                <div>{totalExpenses}{currencySymbol}</div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
  }

  export default IncomeExpensesContainer;
```

How could `value` be used just an initial value of the input field?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `defualtValue` prop instead. See [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).

> In the React rendering lifecycle, the `value` attribute on form elements
> will override the value in the DOM. With an uncontrolled component,
> you often want React to specify the initial value, but leave
> subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify
> a `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`.

```
<InputItem 
  onBlur={setIncome}
  title="Income" 
  type="number" 
  placeholder="Your income" 
  defaultValue={income}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, if I replace `value` by `defaultValue`, the initial value i=of the input equals to zero

Comment: @grubbyGerbil Sorry, where is there an `i=` in your snippet?

Comment: sorry, I meant "the initial value of the input equals to zero"

Comment: @grubbyGerbil The initial value is the `income` prop that is passed. Are you saying that `income` isn't the value you expect it to be when `IncomeExpensesContainer` component is mounted? Can you add the parent component to your question?

Comment: Dear Drew, I've finally figured out the solution and have posted it as an answer to my  question.

Comment: 1) created const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState(income); and assigned value={insertedValue}
2) used useEffect(() => {  setInsertedValue(income)  }, [income]);

Comment: @grubbyGerbil Yeah, that was going to be my suggestion if you had the need to respond to the `income` prop value changing after `IncomeExpensesContainer` was mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution:

- created const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState(income); and assigned value={insertedValue}
- used `useEffect(() => {  setInsertedValue(income)  }, [income]);`

This is the updated code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import InputItem from './InputItem';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    income: string;
    setIncome: (value: string) => void; 
    totalExpenses: number;
    currencySymbol: string;
}

const IncomeExpensesContainer: React.FC<Props> = ({
        income,
        setIncome, 
        totalExpenses, 
        currencySymbol,
    }: Props) => {

    const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState<string>(income);

    // Initializing didMount as false
    const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);

    // Setting didMount to true upon mounting
    useEffect(() => { setDidMount(true) }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => { 
        setInsertedValue(income) 
    }, [income]);

   useEffect(() => {
        if (didMount) {
            axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/income')
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/income', 
            {
                income: income
            });
        }
    }, [didMount,income]);
 
    return (
        <Grid container spacing={1} className="income-expenses-container">
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <InputItem 
                    onChange={setInsertedValue}
                    onBlur={setIncome}
                    title="Income" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Your income" 
                    value={insertedValue}
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} className="centered">
                <h3>Total Expenses</h3>
                <div>{totalExpenses}{currencySymbol}</div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
  }

  export default IncomeExpensesContainer;
```